# Adding a listener to a view makes the listview item unclickable

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I'm trying to make a custom list.
In the list adapter, I've implemented this code in the getView(..) method:

```
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.layout_main);

        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch (event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        {
                            layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.asia_red_color));
                            return true;
                        }

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        {
                            layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                            return true;
                        }
                    }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Note that the listener that I've implemented prevents/overrides executing the onItemClickListener that I've implemented in MainActivity.

Any solutions?

Comment: have onItemClickListener and use a selector to change the background color on click

Comment: sounds a very good idea.

Comment: check my post and see if it works for you and make sure if you have buttons it does not take focus when you click listview items and remove touch listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just `OnItemClickListener`

Define a selector

bkg.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
</selector>
```

set the selector to listview. To the custom layout `android:background="@drawable/bkg"`

Define colors in color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
</resources>
```

Also check if your lsitview row items has buttons. When you click the button may take focus.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, but with `state_pressed` not `state_selected`. Can you provide a general solution? What if I want to do something other than changing the background color?

Comment: @HamzehSoboh what do you mean by generalized solution and yes its state_pressed and what is that you intend to do

Comment: I mean that may be I need to call a method for example, then I don't need the OnItemClickListener in my MainActivity to be ignored, since this what is actually happening now.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh onItemclicklistener will work remove ontouch listener and if it does not work check if you have buttons in listitem imageviews

Comment: @HamzehSoboh use it like `listView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){public void onItemClcick...});` use it in activity where you initialize listview

Comment: yes it will work if I remove the OnToutchListener. But what if I need it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40315/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-hamzeh-soboh)

Comment: @HamzehSoboh you can't have both it will not work that's the reason i asked you to use selector and only OnItemClickListener and remove the touch listener

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is happening here, but you can try to invoke the `OnTouchListener` of the super class in the `default` branch of the `switch`, something like this:

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.asia_red_color));
                        return true;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    {
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        return true;
                    }
                    default: return super.OnTouchListener();
                }

        }
    });
```

Pardon me if the syntax is incorrect, since I am on just the browser at the moment, but you get the idea.